# MYSQL - Using AVG() and DISTINCT together

Tags: sql, mysql, distinct, average

How can you write the following in MYSQL?

```
SELECT AVG(col1) FROM table WHERE DISTINCT col2
```

more info:

```
table

col1 | col2
-----------
2    | 555.555.555.555
5    | 555.555.555.555
4    | 444.444.444.444
```

returns '3'

Basically I'm trying to select **average** value of **col1** where ip addresses in **col2** are **distinct**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  SELECT col2, 
         AVG(col1) 
    FROM table 
GROUP BY col2
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to get AVG() of the entire column?

Comment: `select avg(col1) from table` would give you the average of the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

Right, because the distinct clause would find the first and third rows, the average of 2 and 4 is 3.

What I think you're looking for is "group by col2" instead of distinct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `group by` operator.  It will group the rows before running calculations on them.